# Xstream toXml not serializing base class

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, xstream

I have a class with the following structure which i am trying to serialize using Xstream

```
public class Child extends Parent implements Serializable {
   private String prop1;
   private String prop2;
   // some getter setters
}
```

Class **parent** looks like this

```
 public class Parent implements Serializable {
   private String prop3;
   private String prop4;
   // some getter setters
}
```

I am trying to serialize the **Child** class like this.

```
    Child child = new Child();
    child.setProp1("test desc");
    child.setProp2("test name");
    child.setProp3("xyz");
    child.setProp4(true);

    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    String xmlData = xstream.toXML(virtualTerminalProfile);
```

but somehow the xml formed is like following

```
<com.company.Child>
  < prop1>test name</prop1>
  <prop2>test desc</prop2>
</com.company.Child>
```

I am not seeing `prop3` and `prop4` in the xml.

I am not sure what i am missing ?

I am using **xstream 1.4.4**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved after upgrading to xstream version 1.4.10.
May be its a bug in 1.4.4. I did check the release notes but couldn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 1):

I just hit this issue.
It's a bug in OrderRetainingMap. And it's fixed in 1.4.7 release.